# Cauchy Principal Value

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Cauchy principal value of the following integration gives nothing in Mathematica.

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\text{dx}}{x-2}$

I tried some hand calculation which is

$\lim\limits_{\substack{R\rightarrow\infty\\\epsilon\rightarrow 0}}\int\limits_{-R}^{2-\epsilon}\frac{\text{dx}}{x-2}+\lim\limits_{\substack{R\rightarrow\infty\\\epsilon\rightarrow 0}}\int\limits_{2+\epsilon}^{R}\frac{\text{dx}}{x-2}$

$=\lim\limits_{\substack{R\rightarrow\infty\\\epsilon\rightarrow 0}}\left.\ln(x-2)\right\rvert_{-R}^{2-\epsilon}+\lim\limits_{\substack{R\rightarrow\infty\\\epsilon\rightarrow 0}}\left.\ln(x-2)\right\rvert_{2+\epsilon}^{R}$

$=\lim\limits_{\substack{R\rightarrow\infty\\\epsilon\rightarrow 0}}\ln\frac{2-\epsilon-2}{-R-2}+\lim\limits_{\substack{R\rightarrow\infty\\\epsilon\rightarrow 0}}\frac{R-2}{2+\epsilon-2}$

$=\lim\limits_{\substack{R\rightarrow\infty\\\epsilon\rightarrow 0}}\ln\left(\frac{-\epsilon}{-R-2}\times\frac{R-2}{\epsilon}\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty}\ln\left(\frac{R-2}{R+2}\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1-2/R}{1+2/R}\right)$

$=\ln(1)=0$

I used the following command

```
Integrate[1/(x - 2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

which returns the same.

However,

```
Integrate[1/((x - 2) (x - 3)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

returns zero. Why the first one fails to compute the result? (Or am I doing anything wrong in the calculation?)

Comment: First one fails due to divergence at +-infinity, which are not first order poles for the function.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  But, any antisymmetric integrand integrated over the real line must integrate to zero.  (There is no difference between `1/(x - 2)` and `1/x` in this regard.)

Comment: @ bbgodfrey So `Integrate[1/x, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]` claims divergence, for eactly the same reason.